# jquery dialog load url with datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have built 2 pages , 1 that is the page where there is a link that opens a dialog and loads another page inside that dialog, once the dialog opens and loads the other page this one has a calendar but when i click on the calendar it gives the following error: Cannot read property 'inline' of undefined

i cannot interpretate what is wrong as if i run the file where the datepicker is it runs the calendar but once i execute from the first page by opening the dialog it gives error.

below there's the source for page1 and page2:

```
<!--PAGE1.PHP-->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"  />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
function loadurl() {
$(function() {
    $("#dialog").load('page2.php').dialog({modal:true}); 
});
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<a href="#" onClick="return val()">teste</a>
<div id="dialog" title="Dialog"></div>

</body>
</html>


<!-- PAGE2.PHP -->


<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"  />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

### $.load does not run script on loaded page

The script will not be run on the new page because the ready function on the original page does not fire it. Any script that is meant for the second page needs to be run in the success listener of the $.load function on the first page

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things with the code. First of all, you need to decide what `PAGE2.php` is; is it a component of a page or a standalone page. `.load()` inserts the downloaded code directly into the DOM. So, you could strip PAGE2.php down to:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>
```

Or, you could load a portion of the download page with `.load()` by providing a selector: e.g. `$('#dialog').load('page2.php #datepicker')`.

Another thing is the statement to load PAGE2.php into the DOM, i.e. `$("#dialog").load('page2.php').dialog({modal:true})`. What you want to do is to load the page first (probably in the background) before rendering it with `.dialog()`. So, it should be something like:

```
$("#dialog").load('page2.php', function() { $(this).dialog({modal:true})​ })​
```

Comment: Hi William , it works very well. Many thank's for your help and explanation!

Comment: @user1361389 You're welcome! If you're satisfied with my answer, you should consider "accept" the answer by clicking on the tick below the score.